# JCAPS EDI standard exchange format to Mule ESL format

Tags: mule, edi, x12

I have an EDI SEF (X12 835 template) file which we are using currently. I want to develop application using mule ESB. I have to use X12 connector to read and parse file but in mule i need to pass ".esl" file as schema to parse X12 instead SEF. Is there any way to read EDI (X12 835) and parse it using customized EDI implementation in Mule 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

EDI SEF defines the structure of EDI message. So does Mule ESL. Mule B2B ships with all standard ESL's including the one for X12 835 (check the list [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-b2b/supported-edi-document-types)).

If you have customized the standard definitions then it is possible to extend default 835 ESL and create the new one. See [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-b2b/x12-module#defining-your-implementation-convention-with-an-overlay-schema) for how to overlay standard schemas.